# (R) Loop objects on Environment into a function and export results

Tags: r, function, loops, for-loop

I would like to export plots from several dataframes.

I tried by using a 1)for loop and by passing ls() to a 2)function but in any case, the function I use (regplot) only reaches the character vector: *Error in data[, 1] : incorrect number of dimensions*

1. Example dummy data:

```r
cbind.data.frame(x = 0:6, y = c(1, 2, 3, 6.1, 5.9, 6, 6.1)) -> data1

cbind.data.frame(x = 0:6, y = c(2, 4, 6, 12.2, 11.8, 12, 12.2)) -> data2
```

2. For loop:

```
require(easyreg)

for (i in base::ls()) { i |> easyreg::regplot(model = 3) }
```

3. Trying using a function:

```
test_fun <- function(x) { x |> regplot(model=3) }

test_fun(ls())
```

4. What I'd like to do:

```
for (i in base::ls()) {
  svglite::svglite(filename = paste0(i,".svg"))
  i |> easyreg::regplot(model = 3)
  dev.off()
}
```

Comment: (1) Typo in your code, you're missing a quote after `".svg`. (2) You can use `get(i) |> easyreg:regplot(model=3)`. (3) The use of `base::ls()` is likely to be a bit over-eager; I suggest limiting your search with with `ls(pattern=...)` or some other method for ensuring you don't use every other object. For instance, if you run this once and then run it again, you'll find the object `i` which will obviously not contain something that can be passed to `regplot`.

Comment: What do you mean by "export plots" ? Save the images of the plot in a folder ?

Comment: Thanks for the input. I tried to be as most straightfoward as possible when describing my issue, sorry if it wasn't that clear at first glance. I have tons os scripts I'd like to improve readability and automation and I never was able to get it done. EDIT: I intended to export several svg plots as in the code shown in part 3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can skip the steps 2. and 3.

```r
# require(svglite)
for (i in ls(pattern = "data")) { # Assuming that all the dataframes'names contain the word "data"
  svglite::svglite(filename = paste0(i,".svg"))
  get(i) |> easyreg::regplot(model = 3)
  dev.off()
}
```

Inspired by [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73091313/r-loop-objects-on-environment-into-a-function-and-export-results/73091463#comment129090385_73091313)

Comment: As mentioned before, I have tons os scripts I never was able to get past this part: that a function read an vector containing objects to be looped. I'm gonna read get() documentation and look for some other examples. Many thanks. EDIT: I tried to thumbs up your answer but I got not enough rep in Stackoverflow. =/

Comment: So your problem is still unsolved ?

Comment: Problem solved. Sorry I didn't check it before. <3